# for (NSArray *a in directory) doesn't work as I would expect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foreach, nsarray

After loading a plist into an NSArray I'm trying to access its nested arrays.

```
NSArray *tree = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
for (NSArray *a in tree)
{
    //Let's assume object at index 0 is always NSString
    NSLog(@"Returning the string: %@ ", [a objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Some values from the debugger:

```
   tree __NSCFArray *   0x6856cf0
   0    __NSCFString *  0x6818b70
   1    __NSCFString *  0x682be10
   2    __NSCFArray *   0x6856cd0
```

So I'm expecting the for statement to skip the first 2 NSStrings and then execute with the NSArray.

However stepping one line:
a   __NSCFString *  0x6818b70

And boom, appcrash.

Tips?

Comment: Specifying the exact error message (likely an uncaught exception) you're getting would help.

Answer (score 6):

> So I'm expecting the for statement to skip the first 2 NSStrings and then execute with the NSArray.

That is not what the `for (NSArray *a in tree)` expression does. That statement creates a local variable named `a` of type `NSArray *` and assigns it to reference each object in `tree`, regardless of if the object at a particular index is an NSArray or not.

Your fast enumeration loop is roughly equivalent to:

```
NSArray *a;
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [tree count]; index++) {
  a = [tree objectAtIndex:index];
  ...
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html

Answer (score 5):

As Jonah already pointed out, just telling the compiler that you expect an `NSArray` doesn't actually make it one. If you want to skip objects that aren't arrays in your loop, you could do it as follows:

```
for (NSArray *a in tree) {
    if (![a isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) continue;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As omz & Jonah have pointed out your `for` loop does not also select items simply by specifying the type of `a`. Here is another variation which makes it clear the elements may not be arrays:

```
for (id element in tree)
{
   // skip non-arrays
   if (![element isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) continue;

   NSArray *a = (NSArray *)element;
   ...
}
```

Comment: That's the same as omz's. Why even post it again?

Comment: @ChristianBeer - omz extracted the element into a variable of type `NSArray *` and then checked whether this was valid; the above code extracts the element into a variable of type `id` which is valid and only if it is an array is it assigned to a variable of type `NSArray *`. Especially given that the question involves a confusion over types being careful with them would seem to be wise and clearer; why assign something to an `NSArray *` knowing full well it may not be of that type?